# Invariant measures

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm working on a paper in which I have to prove that following measure is $T$ invariant.
Notice that $T$ is defined the way like this :

> \begin{align*}
> T: [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1] \\
> T(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> x+ \dfrac{1}{2} & x \in [0,\dfrac{1}{2}]\\
> 2x-1 & x \in (\dfrac{1}{2} , 1]
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   I'm going to prove that $\mu$ is $T$ invariant
>   \begin{align*}
> \mu = \dfrac{\nu + \nu T}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   in which $\nu$ is a $ T^{2} $ invariant measure with density $h$ with respect to lebesuge measure $m$.

I tried alot :

> As you know we have to prove for any $B$ in $\mathcal{B}[0,1] $ we have :
>   \begin{align*}
> \mu(B) = \mu(T^{-1}B)
> \end{align*}
>   So :
>   \begin{align*}
> \mu(B) = \dfrac{\nu(B) + \nu T(B)}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   And we have :
>   \begin{align*}
> \mu(T^{-1}B) = \dfrac{\nu T^{-1}(B) + \nu(B)}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   So we have to prove that :
>   \begin{align*}
> \nu T (B) = \nu T^{-1}(B)
> \end{align*}
>   We know that $\nu T^{-1}(B) = \int_{T^{-1} (B)} h dm$
>   I computed this :
>   \begin{align*}
> \nu T^{-1}(B) = \dfrac{1}{2} h(\dfrac{x+1}{2}) + h(x - \dfrac{1}{2}) 1 _{[\dfrac{1}{2},1]}(x)
> \end{align*}

I don't know how compute $\nu T(B)$ and when do we use from the fact that $\nu$ is $T^{2}$ invariant ?
Can we say that since $ \nu $ is $ T^{2} $ invariant so :
\begin{align*}
\nu(B) = \nu(T^{-2}(B))
\end{align*}
So we have that :
\begin{align*}
\nu( T T^{-2}(B)) = \nu (TB)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\nu T^{-2}=\nu$, we have 
$$\nu(T(B))=\nu(T^{-2}(T(B)))=\nu(T^{-1}(B)),$$
and thus 
$$\mu(T^{-1}(B))=\frac{1}{2}\left[\nu(T^{-1}(B))+\nu(B)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\nu(T(B))+\nu(B)\right]=\mu(B).$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of $\mu$ as being the average of $\nu$ and $\nu T$. Now if $\nu$ is $T^2$ invariant, this means that $\nu$ and $\nu T^2$ is the same measure and you should be able to conclude directly that $\mu$ is $T$-invariant. (You average along the $T$ orbit using the periodic behaviour of $\nu$.)

Bonus question: If you started with a measure say $\kappa$ which is $T^n$ invariant for some $n$ a fixed natural number. How would you construct a $T$-invariant measure from $\kappa$?